# How to stop drect access to my jsp page even when i am using security-constraint in web.xml in struts 1.2

Tags: java, iframe, struts1, security-constraint

I am using struts 1.2 and using  global-forwards to access my jsp files and had also put security constraint in my web.xml file even after putting  /pages/* in security constraint i can control direct access to my jsp's through url http://localhost:8080/mywebsite/pages/home.jsp but whenever someone point mouse around my menu item he is able to see url like
http://localhost:8080/mywebsite/home.do which i am displaying in iframe and so nothing can stop direct accessing to home.jsp by hitting  above url and able to see home.jsp which i only want to display in iframe of my index.jsp below is the security contraint i am using also i connot use constraint like   `<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>` this will stop even to display home.jsp  in an iframe too .

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>JSP Files</web-resource-name>
        <description>No direct access to JSP files</description>


        <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>

  <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>No direct browser access to JSP files</description>
        <role-name>NobodyHasThisRole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

here is configration in my struts-config.xml

```
<global-forwards>

    <forward name="home" path="/home.do"/>
 </global-forwards>

<action-mappings>
<action  path="/home"  forward="/pages/home.jsp"/>
</action-mappings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place you JSP files under `/WEB-INF`. The server will not serve anything from within the `/WEB-INF` folder. You don't even need a security rule in `web.xml`.
See "Jakarta Struts - Seven Lessons from the Trenches", chapter 4, "[Protect JSPs Behind WEB-INF](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/10/30/jakarta.html?page=3)" for more details.

Having done that you then control acces to you home page through a Struts action. That's the entire idea with using Struts, so that you no longer access JSP files directly but always go through a `*.do` action.

If you want to protect your JSP for all requests except when the requests comes from an `iframe`, then that's not possible.

Comment: see i have already tried this but every browser displays the url information using in the application like this http://localhost:8080/mywebsite/home.do and your home.do is mapped to /WEB-INF/pages/home.jsp in the struts-config.xml so whenever someone click on the url http://localhost:8080/mywebsite/home.do  he will have a direct access to home.jsp

Comment: @SanjeevSingh: what you are trying to do is not straight forward because of how HTTP works. What's so special about home.jsp for you to need this behavior from your app?